# Decode XML/HTML entities from iso-8859-1 charset in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, html-entities

I'm receiving polish text from a SOAP action that has the polish diacritics encoded as XML entities, but as far as I can tell, they are not encoded in UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1 and I'm struggling to decode them properly in NodeJS.

Example text: `Borek Fa&#197;&#130;&#196;&#153;cki`

Expected decoding result: `Borek Fałęcki`

Current result: `Borek FaÅ‚Ä™cki`

While I achieved the correct result in PHP using following code:

```php
echo html_entity_decode('Borek Fa&#197;&#130;&#196;&#153;cki', ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_XML1, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

I'm having no luck in doing the same in NodeJS. There aren't many complete packages to help with decoding html/xml entities, I have used both `entites` and `html-entities` but they provide the same results, and none of them seem to have any charset settings.

```js
const { decode, encode } = require('html-entities');
const entities = require('entities');

const txt = 'Borek Fa&#197;&#130;&#196;&#153;cki';
console.log('html-entities decode', decode(txt));
console.log('utf8-encoding', encode('Borek Fałęcki', {
    mode: 'nonAsciiPrintable',
    numeric: 'decimal',
    level: 'xml',
}));
console.log('entities decode', entities.decodeXML(txt));
```

Output:

```
html-entities decode Borek FaÅ‚Ä™cki
utf8-encoding Borek Fa&#322;&#281;cki
entities decode Borek FaÅ‚Ä™cki
```

As we can see, when encoded with UTF-8 there are single entities for each character:

```
&#322; = ł
&#281; = ę
```

With ISO-8859-1, there are 2 entities per character. I have no more ideas how to achieve the same decoding result as in PHP. If there were no entities, I could just convert the encoding to UTF-8 but with entities I have no idea  how to do it properly. I cannot get the other side to send me UTF-8, since this is a closed old protocol that I have no control of.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it may be for HTML, but in this case the software that sends it in a SOAP Action XML encodes it like that and I have no control of it whatsoever. PHP somehow allows me to decode this properly, but unfortunately I must go with NodeJS

Comment: well, I can't do anything about it and there is noone that can change this. I guess PHP has the charset option for a reason, since it solves the problem. I'm still looking how to replicate the `html_decode_entity` in nodejs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct XML encoding of `Borek Fałęcki` is `Borek Fa&#322;&#281;cki`. The SOAP action XML that you receive is wrongly encoded.

However, the following expression converts it as needed:

```
Buffer.concat(
  "Borek Fa&#197;&#130;&#196;&#153;cki"
  .match(/[^&]+|&#\d+;/g)
  .map(c => c[0] === "&"
    ? Buffer.of(Number(c.substring(2, c.length - 1)))
    : Buffer.from(c))
).toString()
```

Comment: Nice, it works correctly! Trying to understand your code, I just figured out that bytes 197, 130 are actually character `ł` in utf-8 (hex c5 82) which surprises me how did PHP decode it properly with `iso-8859-1` charset.. so it was utf-8 all the time but just the entity conversion is invalid?

Comment: That would be a question for [tag:php]